# how to call a (samename) method declared outside with(){} scope in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to call the dada() declared outside with()
There's a line below that supposed to do what I need but doesn't compile.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var muchos = "muchos"

    fun dada(){
        println("dada")}
    var someRun = Runnable { println(muchos) }

    with(someRun){
        fun dada(){
            println("dodo")}
        run()
        muchos = "holas"
        //*********************//DOES'T COMPILE *******************
        this@OuterClass.dada() //DOES'T COMPILE *******************
        run()

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't compile because `dada` is defined inside `fun main()` not in `OuterClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin does not provide a syntax for disambiguating between multiple local functions with the same name. The `OuterClass` in the `this@OuterClass` syntax is the name of a specific class that was used in the example where you copied this line from; it does not have a generic meaning of "outer scope".

To make it possible to call both functions, simply give them different names.

Comment: Or you can give them different parameters.  (Though different names are often clearer.)